# PrestaShop - Get cart content in other checkout steps

Tags: prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to display cart content in the address and shipping pages of the checkout. So far I could only display the order subtotals and totals :

```
{$cart->getOrderTotal(true)}
{$cart->getOrderTotal(true, 1)}
```

I didn't find any method to get this information inside the .tpl files. I'm using PrestaShop 1.6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$cart` variable is an object so you should be able to use any public method in `Cart` class.

So you could write this to list product names in cart.

```
{foreach from=$cart->getProducts() item=product}
    {$product.name}
{/foreach}
```